# How to check assert which returns the list of boolean?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit

This one is ok , it is working.
`assert(Class.method()[0].example.name == "example"`

But how can I check all of names, not only one.
`assert(Class.method().map {it.example.name == "example"})`
Here I become error that requiered Boolean, but get `List<Boolean>`.
How can I change assert to the list assert?

Answer (score 2):

`map` is a function that transforms the current list into a new list. What you want is a function that checks if all elements of the list match a condition. This is what the [all](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html) function is meant to do:

```kotlin
assert(Class.method().all { it.example.name == "example" })
```

Note that maybe you should use assertions that check equality between different things rather that basic boolean assertions. It would give you better error messages if the assertion fails.